# heroku node.js tutorial app not running

Tags: node.js, heroku

Trying to deploy the heroku node.js tutorial and I'm at the "Deploy locally portion" https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#run-the-app-locally

When I try to run the app, I get

```
[node-js-getting-started]$ heroku local web
[OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format
18:47:54 web.1   |  Listening on 5000
```

I can see it when I run a ps

```
[node-js-getting-started]$ ps
PID TTY           TIME CMD
5524 ttys001    0:00.03 /Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2 --server login -fp Kevin
5526 ttys001    0:00.04 -bash
6050 ttys001    0:00.98 vi README.md
5495 ttys002    0:00.03 /Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2 --server login -fp Kevin
5497 ttys002    0:00.11 -bash
6061 ttys003    0:00.04 /Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm2 --server login -fp Kevin
6063 ttys003    0:00.02 -bash
6315 ttys003    0:00.02 heroku local web
6316 ttys003    0:00.01 bash /Users/Kevin/.local/share/heroku/client/bin/heroku local web
6321 ttys003    0:00.00 bash /Users/Kevin/.local/share/heroku/client/bin/../7.0.17/bin/heroku local web
6327 ttys003    0:00.00 bash /Users/Kevin/.local/share/heroku/client/bin/heroku local web
6332 ttys003    0:00.01 bash /Users/Kevin/.local/share/heroku/client/bin/../7.0.17/bin/heroku local web
6340 ttys003    0:00.28 /Users/Kevin/.local/share/heroku/client/7.0.17/bin/node /Users/Kevin/.local/share/heroku/client/7.0.17/bin/run local web
6341 ttys003    0:00.12 /Users/Kevin/.local/share/heroku/client/7.0.17/bin/node /Users/Kevin/.local/share/heroku/client/7.0.17/node_modules/@heroku-c
6342 ttys003    0:00.18 node index.js
```

But when I go to http://localhost:5000 I just get a blank page.

Not sure where to find logs, which config file I should be looking at.

Thanks

Comment: Your logs should be shown in the terminal where you ran `heroku local web`. You should see requests come in there and responses go out.

Comment: Not seeing anything in the terminal where I typed "heroku local web". The last thing I see is "Listening on 5000"